# Need some advice to get a commercial xmpp application developed

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, whatsapp

I have a business idea which I want to materialize for sometime .. I recently shared my idea with 2 close friends who also found it very interesting, new and doable plus the cost included for the project to start is reasonable and they have planned to invest in it. Much of the success of this project app depends on the proper marketing  element out of which most of the time, you have to personally meet up with clients/vendor and make them use your application.

The idea is to connect  local ecommerce (retail shops, businesses, vendors, etc.) with users/customers through a messaging app mostly similar to whatsapp. I have already started to look for a xmpp/jabber developer who can accomplish our requirements. We are expecting him to develop the app and also set-up the server requirements. Our budget lies within $3000-4000 range for the project to initiate.

I want the app to have the following aspects:

a) user friendly GUI

b) highly scalable (planning to start within my city located in south asia)

c) location sharing (want users to navigate nearby shops/vendor offering their type of goods/services)

d) have a user review feedback against vendors and an additional page for vendor profile/rating system

e) only customer - vendor chats with functionalities like camera snaps, audio recording (just like whatsapp).

f) both for ios and android

Now the whole idea outlaid, after reading lots of articles, discussion and tutorials, I  have some questions (I am a non-technical person btw):

1- I believe ejabberd is the best option as compared to tigase or prosody due to high scability. Is this ok to go with or should I look at other xmpp servers?

2- Currently, I am planning to launch this application within my city (rated as worldwide no.2 as per population stats of above 25m people), should I set-up a local server with high internet bandwith and a powerful machine or should I outsource it to some xmpp hosted server in the US (as their technological infrastructure has always provided quality service).
3- Should I be worried about the developer stealing the source code or is there any effective way to minimize this risk?
4- Any ideas what other things I am missing. This is dead serious for me and I am willing to do anything to get this project on the road.

(P.S.: The idea for this app is similar to the existing app called Lookup but I am planning to add some variations to it)

Thanks and sorry for being a bit lengthy ..

Regards,
Ahmed

Comment: Not a development related question

Comment: order me a gig in fiverr.... :p

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd is indeed likely your best bet. However, be careful about the budget. To launch a quality service in an highly competitive area you have to have a significant budget, both development and marketing, if you expect your project to succeed.